# PHP System Test - 1600 line procedural script

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, system

I've been given the task of system testing a PHP script that is approximately 1600 lines long and runs every minute via a cron.  The script is 100% procedural and starts off with 30+ require_once() calls which bring in the whole codebase.  This how the system was designed from the beginning.

I've been told refactoring isn't an option since there are currently no test cases in place.

**Question:**
I ran into a 'new' class constructor in the middle of the script.  This class constructor creates a factory in a different class.  I don't care about the class constructor or factory.  Is there a way to bypass the functionality without having to mock, stub, etc?

**Problems:**
-The require() at the start of the script prevents me from creating a stub since I can't have two functions with the same name. (real function and stub function)
-The 'new' is in the middle of the script so I can't add a mock to the object created.

Comment: Man, this sounds a heck of a lot like the code I have to deal with at work.  I'm not going to post this as an answer, as it's unproductive, but I'd say this: forget *unit* testing for now.  You can perform automated *integration* testing on the script and slowly build up a *unit* suite as you refactor.  Sure, integration testing is nastier and harder (especially forging data to do things like force error states for better code coverage), but it's going to be a heck of a lot more achievable short-term, and at least it'll give you *some* variety of testing ability.

Comment: Dear! [Michael Feathers](http://www.objectmentor.com/omTeam/feathers_m.html) wrote [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052), which lists techniques to use in this kind of hard-pressed no-tests-exist situation. The examples he uses are not PHP, but the techniques and the discussion of them are quite useful. Recommended reading. See the Amazon reviews, which paint a picture of the book's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand your whole problem, but reading the last part of your question, about stub functions and similair, maybe you should learn more about just *how* dynamic php can be.

For instance:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php

So basically you could rename the function you want to stub, and create a new one with the same name, and if you want, call the old function by its new name from the new function.

There are a lot of these things for manipulating classes, functions, and so on, some of them in a form of extensions and are really quite hacky (especially this whole extension http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), but for testing purposes, why not?

Comment: I believe you will have to install the APD extension to get that functionality.